# Set Text to the RichTextBlock in code behind

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, uwp, windows-10-universal

I am trying to set Text to a RichTextBlock in a universal app,this is my code in xaml:

```
<RichTextBlock x:Name="descr">
       <Paragraph>
             <Paragraph.Inlines>
                 <Run Text="{Binding Path=desc}"/>
             </Paragraph.Inlines>
       </Paragraph>
</RichTextBlock>
```

but I dont know how to set Text in this RichTextBlock in code behind,this is my try:

```
Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
  p.Inlines.Add("test");//error here cannot convert from 'string' to 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Documents.Inline' 
  descr.Blocks.Add(p);
```

so how can I set Text to the RichTextBlock in code behind C#
thanks for help

Comment: If you already have defined binding, why not to use it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Inlines property is an [InlineCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.documents.inlinecollection) which is a collection of
[Inline](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.documents.inline%20Inline) objects, while you are trying to add a string to this collection.

MSDN for Inline

> Provides a base class for inline text elements, such as Span and Run.

So you need to add either a [Run](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.documents.run) or Span object instead.

```
// Create run and set text
Run run = new Run();
run.Text = "test";

// Create paragraph
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();

// Add run to the paragraph
paragraph.Inlines.Add(run);

// Add paragraph to the rich text block
richTextBlock.Blocks.Add(paragraph);
```

**Edit**

Seems like you cannot directly bind Text property of a Run or Span object from the code behind.

Comment: thanks Sir for your reply,but I get an error at the line :  run.SetBinding(TextProperty, binding); =>'Run' does not contain a definition for 'SetBinding' and no extension method 'SetBinding' accepting a first argument of type 'Run' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @user3821206 oh yea, I updated the answer, the error was due to binding issue with Run, maybe it is not supported or something. I'll update the answer if I find a way to bind the Run from the code behind.